# how to create array php into blank braces

Tags: php, api, cloudflare

i'm trying to make a php array, i need to create array with blank braces variable like {}, but if i use array() the data shows [] square bracket, how to create variable into {}

php code:

```
<?php

    $newArray = array("name"=>"SMK Bina Rahayu", "grade"=>"below", "parent"=>array());

    $afterEncode = json_encode($newArray);

    print_r($afterEncode);

?>
```

the result :

```
{
  "name": "SMK Bina Rahayu",
  "grade": "below",
  "parent": [
    
  ]
}
```

the result that i need or i want:

```
{
  "name": "SMK Bina Rahayu",
  "grade": "below",
  "parent": {}
}
```

is it possible to make the blank array from square bracket into braces?
i need to change it because i want to use cloudflare api that only accept braces in blank variable and not square brackets

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways I can think of ... The `{}` indicated an object, so

```
$newArray = array("name"=>"SMK Bina Rahayu", "grade"=>"below", "parent"=>(object)array());
$afterEncode = json_encode($newArray);
// or
$newArray = array("name"=>"SMK Bina Rahayu", "grade"=>"below", "parent"=> new stdClass);
$afterEncode = json_encode($newArray);
print_r($afterEncode);
```

RESULT

```
{"name":"SMK Bina Rahayu","grade":"below","parent":{}}
```